# Sculpting is hard. Any other way to make a drop?

Tags: sculpting

I wanted to make a drop of liquid (foundation) that is smooth and curvy.
Like:

[image]

I would prefer the liquid being outside the dropper like so:

[image]

I tried using sculpting which I'm *quite* new to and the result has been disastrous

[image]

Should I spend some more time learning sculpting or is there a better way to get the curvy, stretching liquid drop?

Comment: you could try implementing an actual liquid simulation, but that would be hard to get the effect that you're looking for

Answer (score 3):

Start with your dropper object, and add a loop cut where you want your paint line to be.

[image: Dropper1]

Select the whole bottom (painted) section, right-click and choose "extrude faces along normals" to bring the sides out a little bit (to mimic paint thickness).

[image: Dropper2]

Bring down the bottom center of the dropper and scale it inwards to make a "point".

[image: Dropper3]

Extrude the center section a couple of times and then scale the center line to make a shape like this:

[image: Dropper4]

To make everything round, add a *Subdivision Surface Modifier*. You may need to add some supporting geometry (such as the highlighted loop cut) to control the roundness the way you like. Don't forget to right-click and shade smooth when you're done.

[image: Dropper5]

Finally, just assign the correct materials to the different sections.

[image: Dropper6]

Comment: Thank you! This is so much easier than what I was going to do. Saved me a lot of time and effort.

Answer (score 2):

For still image ...

- add Plane, delete all vertices, with Ctrl+click shape half of silhouette
- add Screw modifier, Apply
- adjust manually vertices to final shape
- add Subsurf modifier
- add Solidify modifier

[image]

Comment: I'm such a newbie, I didnt understand the first bullet. But I do know how to model. Should I just model out a drop I like and then adjust it to my dropper? Thank you for your answer and effort! Really appreciate it!

Comment: When you ad a Plane object to your scene, go to edit mode, delete all vertices of Plane. Than when you press Ctrl and click with mouse you create a new vertex. With other click another one. Like that follow shape on image to get half of silhouette of the chocolate cream (orange line in my screen).

Comment: Quickly in motion https://imgur.com/e1KK5mG

Comment: oh man, this is insanely helpful. I had no idea this is possible. Thanks a bunch!!